# executing the c-program on a 32-bit machine

Tags: c

On a 32-bit system where the addresses start from 1000 what will be the following address values?

```
int main()
{
  int a[10];
  a;
  a++;
  &a+1;
}
```

I have tried to print the same into the print statements but that gives me error.

Comment: `a++;` can't.  `a` is a constant, which means the array.

Comment: *What* address starts at `1000`? Of the array? You do know that arrays are fixed in place, you can't modify the placement of an array, which means any expression attempting to modify the arrays placement (like e.g. `a++`) is invalid.

Comment: Also I recommend you read [this blog post of mine](https://ghost.pileborg.se/2016/08/28/the-difference-between-arrays-decaying-to-pointers-and-pointers-to-arrays/), it tries to explain arrays and pointers and all that. Most importantly it "shows" the difference between `a + 1` and `&a + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You cant increment the value of the fixed size array like `int a[10]` or `char str[10]`. address increment is possible on pointers.
for example

```
char *a="abcd";
printf("%p",a); //prints the address of a lets take 1000
a++; //increments the address by 1( size of character is 1 byte);
printf("%p",a);  //prints 1001
```

but in the case of integer, for example

```
int *a={1,2,3,4};
printf("%p",a); //prints the address of a, lets take 1000
a++;
printf("%p",a) //prints 1004 (because the size of integer in 32 bit machine is 4 bytes.
```

Comment: It's best to always use `%p` to print pointers. It makes your code correct even if you port it to a 64-bits machine.

Comment: Thanks , I modified it.